# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'vocabulary_size')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, streamlit

Having an **issue when loading my LSTM model using Keras** when running my Streamlit application. The error says:

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'vocabulary_size')
```

I think that this issue is due to the TextVectorizer layer in my `tf.keras.Sequential()`. The layer is called `encoder` in my code.

Training Code:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf 

tfds.disable_progress_bar()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graphs(history, metric):
    plt.plot(history.history[metric])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_'+metric], '')
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel(metric)
    plt.legend([metric, 'val_'+metric])


dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']

BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

VOCAB_SIZE = 1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(train_dataset.map(lambda text, label: text))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()),
        output_dim=64,
        mask_zero=True
    ),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
             optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
             metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10,
                   validation_data=test_dataset,
                   validation_steps=30)

## I tried two different ways to save the model but both resulted in the same error
## Method 1:
model.save('model/')

## Method 2:
model_json = model.to_json()
with open('model.json', 'w') as js:
    js.write(model_json)
model.save_weights('model', save_format='tf')
```

Loading the model code:

```
## Loaded the model in two differnt ways based on the save methods
## Method 1:
lstm_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/')

## Method 2:
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
lstm_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

lstm_model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

*[Additional Links]*

My [Github Repo](https://github.com/Harsh188/100-Days-of-ML-Pt2/tree/master/Streamlit-Deployment/LSTM) contains the `LSTM_model.ipynb` notebook which I trained as well as the Streamlit `App.py` which loads in the Keras model.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HolAe.png)

Comment: Code needs to be included in the question, not as external links. And no screenshots of code of code or error messages.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've updated my body to include the code.

Comment: I could train and load the given code on Tenosrflow 2.5.0 without any error. Try with Tensorflow latest version. Thanks!